# JQuery Append if condition

Tags: jquery

Could you please help on how to add if condition to the below snippet?

Snippet:

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
$('#accNo12').empty();
if (DataType == "json") {
$('#accNo12').append("<div id=\"Search\" class=\"results\">"+
"<span id=\"lb\">Account No:"+result.U_ID+"</span></div>"+
"<label>RelMgr: </label>"+
"<span id=\"RID\">"+result.REL_NAME +"</span><br />"+
  "<label>Off ID: </label><span id=\"OffId\">"+ result.SO+"</span><br/>");
       }
}
```

how do i add an if condition to the above snippet in the case where i needed a condition as

```
if(result.SO==""){
<label>Off ID: </label><span id=\"OffId\">"+ result.SO+"</span><br/>"
}
else
{
 <label>Off ID: </label><span id=\"OffId\">No ID found</span><br/>"
}
```

Appreciate if you could help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
  $('#accNo12').empty();
  if (DataType == "json") {
    $('#accNo12').append("<div id=\"Search\" class=\"results\">"+
    "<span id=\"lb\">Account No:"+result.U_ID+"</span></div>"+
    "<label>RelMgr: </label>"+
    "<span id=\"RID\">"+result.REL_NAME +"</span><br />"+
    "<label>Off ID: </label><span id=\"OffId\">"+(result.SO || "No ID found")+"</span><br/>");
  }
}
```